# Logical OR on two lists of boolean

Tags: c#, list, linq, boolean, logical-operators

I have two `bool` lists, both of which will always be of the same length. Suppose these are my two lists:

```
var list1 = new List<bool>() { true, false, true, false, false };
var list2 = new List<bool>() { true, true, true, false, true };
```

I'd like to create a new list by applying the logical `OR` operator to each corresponding index on either list. So, if my two lists were the above, my expected result would be the following.

> true, true, true, false, true

Now, I can easily do this by using a `for` loop like this:

```
var result = new List<bool>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    result.Add(list1[i] || list2[i]);
}
```

This works perfectly well, and isn't even necessarily inefficient. But in my application I have more than 2 lists, even 20 sometimes, and I'll need to get the `OR` of all of them.

Is there an easier way of doing this, considering all lists?

Comment: Do you know about `.Zip()`?

Comment: @gunr2171 not really. Let me look it up.

Comment: Attempting to synchronize lists of the same length is usually a symptom of [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) and is solved by creating a class that contains the data. Properties like the logical OR of two values can be class properties.

Comment: @DourHighArch, the lists are in fact properties of a class. I'm developing a WPF app with a datagrid, where I show/hide columns depending on the contents of these lists. The datagrid displays contents of files, and since I don't know which files user will select, I don't know how many columns there will be in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment on Pavel Anikhouski's answer, you mentioned multiple lists.  I'll expand on that answer by using the `Aggregate` extension method.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<bool> OrBooleanSequences(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool>> source)
{
    return source.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x || y));
}
```

Simply pass the lists as an array or other enumerable and then reify the result.

```cs
var list1 = new List<bool>() { true, false, true, false, false, false };
var list2 = new List<bool>() { true, true, true, false, true, false };
var list3 = new List<bool>() { false, true, false, true, true, false };

var result = ZipMultiple(new[] { list1, list2, list3 }).ToList();
```

---

**EDIT**

On @Theodor Zoulias's recommendation, I've renamed the method above. I chose `OrBooleanSequences`.  The name is fairly arbitrary, though, so if you use it and you want to name it something else that makes better sense to you, more power to you.

And so, this leads to a more generalized method that I'll call `AggregateSequences` and it would be a high-order function taking a function that describes how to perform the aggregation (`resultSelector` here and in the `Zip` overloads).

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AggregateSequences<TSource>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> resultSelector)
{
    return source.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Zip(b, resultSelector));
}
```

...and you would pass the logical OR operation to it as a lambda.

```cs
var result = AggregateSequences(new[] { list1, list2, list3 }, (x, y) => x || y).ToList();
```

This could be used for other operations, like summing elements in a list:

```cs
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };
var list3 = new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 };

var result = AggregateSequences(new[] { list1, list2, list3 }, (x, y) => x + y).ToList();
```

Result:

```
[ 12, 15, 18 ]
```

This method is just one variation, of course.  `Zip` and `Aggregate` have multiple overloads that could be combined.  I'm not sure all combinations make sense but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Perfect, this is really what I wanted.

Comment: @gunr2171, I think it was by about 20s. Haha.

Comment: Instead of `ZipMultiple` you could name it with something having "Or" as a component. Or even simply `Or`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: That makes sense. Let me think about it a bit. Sounds like a good candidate for a high-order function.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Let me know what you think of the edit.

Comment: Two words: I approve. 

Comment: Thanks for making the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`IEnumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) for that

```cs
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (first, second) => first || second);
```

It produces a result sequence by applying a logical OR to every pair of elements from two source sequences.

Comment: How would I extend this to 3 or more lists? Suppose I have 5 or even 20?

Comment: @Sach IMO, in this case the regular loop will be more readable:) but let me think about it

Comment: I came up with this `var result = (list1.Zip(list2, (first, second) => first || second)).Zip(list3, (first, second) => first || second);` which I guess is fine for 3 the most, but beyond that it does look like good old for loops will in fact be clearer to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a list of lists:

```
var listsOfLists = new List<IEnumerable<bool>>
{
    new List<bool>() { true, false, true, false, false },
    new List<bool>() { true, true, true, false, true },
    new List<bool>() { true, false, true, false, false },
    new List<bool>() { true, false, true, true, true }
};
```

Using Linq you can use a combination of `Aggregate` and `Zip`

```
var combinedResults = listsOfLists
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a
        .Zip(b, (aElement, bElement) => aElement || bElement)
     );
```

`Zip` will pair every element in the two selected lists and run the "or" operator against those element pairs, giving you a new bool list. That resulting list will be used in the next Aggregate operation.